# Hyperplane sections of principal homogeneous spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, motives

Let $P_i$ denote the $i$-th vertex in the Dynkin diagramm of an algebraic group. It symbolizes a parabolic subgroup of $G$ corresponding to the other vertices, meaning $G/P_i$ is a smooth, projective, homogeneous $G$-variety.

I recently learned that $ X:=F_4/P_4$ is a hyperplane section of $Y:=E_6/P_6$. One obtains the Hasse diagramm of CH(X) by removing one dot in the Hasse diagramm of CH(Y) in degrees $8,12,16$, which is reflected by the fact that the Grothendieck-Chow motive of $Y$ has one more summand $R(8)$, namely a generalized Rost-Motive corresponding to $g_3 \in H^3(k,\mu_3)$ and thus splitting into

$\overline{R(8)} =$ $(\mathbb{Z}$ $ \oplus $ $\mathbb{Z}(4)$ $\oplus $ $\mathbb{Z}(8))(8)$

Question: Are there other examples of algebraic groups $G,H$ with parabolic subgroups $P_i,P_j$
such that $G/P_i$ is a hyperplane section of $H/P_j$ known?

Comment: A smooth hyperquadric in $\mathbb{P}^n$ (say, over an algebraically closed field) is a  homogeneous space under $\mathrm{SO}(n+1)$; a   smooth hyperplane section is again a   hyperquadric, hence homogeneous  under $\mathrm{SO}(n)$. Same with $\mathbb{P}^n$ (homogeneous  under  $\mathrm{PGL}(n+1)$).

Comment: Very good, so far. Edit: Oh this introduces a new question for quadrics! But before i ask, is the same true for an anisotropic quadric (especially k not algebraically closed)?

Comment: Shouldn't the title be about principal homogeneous spaces, rather than groups?

Comment: Yes, i fixed that.

Comment: You might want to take a look at Ahiezer's classification of equivariant 2-Orbit completions in char. 0 (and Knop's amendment in char p).